# How to use a custom font in React Native?

Tags: android, react-native, fonts, assets

I can add 2 font files **one\android\app\src\main\res\assets\fonts** here with ttf format. its name is **Bold** and **normal**

[image]

then I create one file in the root folder with the name of the file **react-native.config.js** and add this code

```
module.exports = {
    project: {
        ios:{},
        android:{}
    },
    assets:['.android/app/src/main/res/assets/fonts/'],
};
```

then I use the font in my code this way

```
 title: {
        fontFamily: 'Bold',
    },
```

[image]

but in my code, it doesn't work where is my mistake help me to solve this error

Answer (score 0):

you need to link the assets to your project.

as starting from react-native 0.69 react-native link has been removed.

run `npx react-native-assset` to link your assets to both platforms

finally make sure you use the original font name not the display name, you can find it in the properties of the font file

Comment: it's also not work for me

Comment: are you sure you're using the right name check the properties of the font file and check the original name not the display name.

Comment: no, the font name is the same as the font file name can you please explain fully about adding a custom font?

Comment: you can follow these steps to add a custom font to your project

1- create an asset folder in your root folder and add your fonts folder in it.
2- open react-native.config.js and add in the assets array the folder path to your fonts.
3- run npx react-native-asset
4- clean your project and then rebuild
5- make sure the font family is your file name

Answer (score 0):

just fire this command in your terminal : - npx react-native-assset

make sure that you have to use same fonts name in your asset file .

if my font name is : ProximaNova-Black

Than I have to write this black:"ProximaNova-Black",